# How to escape a comment in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I have the following line containing a regex using RoR in a view (show.html.haml):

```
- unless @article.content =~ /find(#{image.id})/
```

The problem is that the regex is not evaluated since it's interpreted as a comment. How can I escape the comment?

Comment: Move that piece of code into a helper method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- unless @article.content =~ Regexp.new("find(#{image.id})")
```

or

```
- unless @article.content =~ %r{find(#{image.id})}
```

**Edit:** I guess I did not really answer the question. To escape the comment, take a look at [cyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1028922/cyle)'s answer that suggests using the `\` character.